# OpenCV cv2.imshow displaying black images sometimes

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying out OpenCV on ubuntu 20.04, python 3.7. I have run the following script

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('butterfly.jpg')
cv2.imshow('ImageWindow', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Sometimes I would get the lovely picture of
[the original butterfly image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DUqE.jpg), but sometimes I would get [a small black window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPmvs.png).

The behavior is a bit random, and I am not sure what is causing this issue.

Comment: I just had the same issue.  Randomly the small black window shows, or sometimes it displays the image correctly.   The issue happens within a pipenv environment, and the opencv-python wheel package.   Note that I also have installed the ArchLinux opencv package, and if I use this global installation of opencv, everything works correctly all the time.  So in my case, as a workaround, I will just NOT use pipenv and opencv-python, but stick to the global python and opencv installations provided by the Archlinux package manager.

Comment: So your all code is this and you do nothing else ?

Comment: Yes. Because I noticed this issue when I was running another python program so I decided to experiment with an easier example first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in opencv version `4.3.0`. The fix is to upgrade to a newer version (in my case `4.4.0`):

```
pip install --upgrade opencv-python
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Not with reading from a file but capturing from a windows webcam. Sometimes I got correct images, sometimes only black ones.

```
pip install videocapture pillow
```

solved my problem. Now I get 100% correct images. I don't know why, but it works now.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to do

```py
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

worked for me.

Comment: that is __identical__ to `waitKey()` (no arguments), which OP already does in the question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).